# How do you use a Uri opened with ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree() and query the MediaStore for all audio in that folder?

Tags: android, directory, uri, mediastore, registerforactivityresult

I am trying to get all audio contained in a folder that the user picks.

The user is asked to pick a folder like this

```
        getUri = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree(),
            activityResultCallback
        )
        getUri.launch(null)
```

I am trying to query the folder like this

```
        var selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " != ?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayListOf("")
        if (data != null){
            selection += " AND "
            selection += if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + " LIKE ? "
            } else {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? "
            }
            selectionArgs.add("%$data%")
        }
```

I have tried the following for data

```
uri.path.toString()
uri.encodedPath.toString()
uri.pathSegments.last().toString()
uri.pathSegments.joinToString ("/")
```

None of that is working. The query is empty when there should be three files. These files are in the MediaStore, as a query of all audio files in the MediaStore contains them. The docs are not very helpful (as usual). The stack overflow posts I found leave out how to get a path.

Perhaps I should ask how to get the user to pick a folder and get all the music from the folder they chose? The docs lead me to both code snippets above, so I would be floored if there was no way to connect them (except this is Android I am dealing with, so nothing surprises me anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OpenDocumentTree` gives you access to only the `Uri` you receive and its children. It does not give you access to any path at all, much less one you could use with the `MediaStore` APIs (nor would you want it to, given that the `MediaStore` APIs are terrible to begin with).

Instead, the easiest way to deal with the Uri returned by `OpenDocumentTree` is to pass it to [`DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#fromTreeUri(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)), which gives a `DocumentFile` object that you can call [`listFiles()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#listFiles()) on and use [`getType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#getType()) to search for mime types starting with `audio/`:

```
// Assuming you have your uri returned by OpenDocumentTree
val rootDirectoryFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(uri)
val directories = ArrayDeque(rootDirectoryFile)
val audioFileUris = mutableListOf<Uri>()

// Loop through all of the subdirectories, starting with the root
while (directories.isNotEmpty()) {
    val currentDirectory = directories.removeFirst()

    // List all of the files in the current directory
    val files = currentDirectory.listFiles()
    for (file in files) {
        if (file.isDirectory) {
            // Add subdirectories to the list to search through
            directories.add(file)
        } else if (file.type?.startsWith("audio/")) {
            // Add Uri of the audio file to the list
            audioFileUris += file.uri
        }
    }
}
// Now audioFileUris has the Uris of all audio files
```

Comment: That is kind of like what I ended up doing, although I used the DocumentFile API to get the document displayName, so I could fetch it from the MediaStore. All in all, it ends up adding 70 lines of code to get valid MediaStore ids I can use across app restarts.
Looks like with your method, I would need to get persistent Uri permissions.

Comment: You can [persist access](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions) to the entire directory using its Uri, you don't need MediaStore IDs or need to get persistent Uri permissions to individual Uris. That's 1 line of code that you'd do before this code.

Comment: That sounds like a better approach.

Comment: Can you play the audio files from this with the MediaPlayer?

Comment: MediaPlayer does have an [overload of `setDataSouce`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)) specifically for content uris like these, yes.